# Show that $\pi_{i}(F) \cong \pi_{i +1}(X) $ where $F$ is the homotopy fiber of the inclusion $X \rightarrow X \times X.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, k-theory, fibration

Let $F$ be the homotopy fiber of the inclusion $X \rightarrow X \times X.$

(1)Show that $\pi_{i}(F) \cong \pi_{i +1}(X).$

Could anyone explain to me how to prove this, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We let $f: E \rightarrow B$ be the map obtained by converting $X \rightarrow X \times X$ into a fibration.

Explicitly we let $E = X^I$, $B = X \times X$ and if $p \in X^I$ is a path $I \rightarrow X$,  $f(p) = (p(0),p(1))$. The important property that $f$ has is that it is a fibration and is pointwise homotopy equivalent to $X \rightarrow X \times X$.

Let $x_0 \in X$ be the base point.

The fiber of $f$ is $\Omega X$ since if we let $(x_0, x_0)$ be the base point of $X \times X$, $f^{-1}((x_0, x_0)) = \{p:I \rightarrow X: (p(0),p(1)) = (x_0, x_0)\}$, the set of all paths in $X$ with start and end point equal to the base point.

Thus since $f$ is a fibrant replacement for $X \rightarrow X \times X$, we know that $F \simeq f^{-1}(x_0,x_0) = \Omega X$ and this isomorphism you are looking for reduces to proving that $\pi_i(\Omega X) = \pi_{i+1}(X)$ which you can find proofs for if you search for "suspension-loop adjunction".

Comment: Can you give a reference for a good book for this proof, please?

Comment: I recommend "Modern classical homotopy theory" which I see that you have been asking questions about. The chapter on homotopy limits will contain what you need. The homotopy fiber of a map $f:A \rightarrow B$  is the homotopy limit of the diagram $* \rightarrow B \xleftarrow f A  $ and if $\mu : I \rightarrow J$ is a natural transformation between diagrams and is a pointwise homotopy equivalence then $\mu$ will induce homotopy equivalence of the homotopy limit. And the homotopy fiber of a fibration is just the fiber at the base point. With these facts you should be able to prove this yourself.